# ndarray value visualization and overwriting in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have ndarray of shape (3,8,1,1,365) where 3 is count (A,B,C) of product, 8 is count of places(AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF,GG,HH), 365 is time frame of data in days. I want to see the values for B and CC combination for 365 days, want to replace these values of A and BB combination. How to do that ?  please help.. tried with ndarray_name.todense()[2][3] to visualize the data but no luck..

Answer (score 0):

This task should be tagged rather as *Numpy*, because *Pandas* does not
serve 5-D arrays.

To create an example array I used the following code:

```
import itertools
s1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
s2 = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'GG', 'HH']
s3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
arr = np.array([ '_'.join(t) for t in itertools.product(s1, s2, s3) ])\
    .reshape((len(s1), len(s2), len(s3)))
```

For the time being *arr* has only 3 dimensions, so to convert it to 5-D
array, run:

```
arr = arr[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]
```

When you `print(arr.shape)`, the result is: `(3, 8, 1, 1, 4)` (4 days instead of 365).

Then, to print your slice, run:

```
arr[1,2]
```

The result is:

```
array(['B_CC_1', 'B_CC_2', 'B_CC_3', 'B_CC_4'], dtype='<U6')
```

i.e.:

- *1* (the first index) - limit the first dimension to the second value (*B*),
- *2* (the second index) - limit the second dimension to the third value (*CC*).

And to replace them with *A* / *BB* values, run:

```
arr[1,2,...] = arr[0,1,...]
```